# animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: not working (strangely)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to translate a UIView for a distance using the following code:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -100);
[self.exposureHintView setTransform:transform];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"Begin!");
                     CGAffineTransform newTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
                     [self.exposureHintView setTransform:newTrans];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"End %d", finished);
                 }];
```

So basically, I'm justing trying to move the view from some point say `(-100, -100)` to where it should be `(0, 0)` relative to itself.

Since I wanted to animate it once the view appeared, so I put the code in `viewDidAppear:`. But when I run the code, nothing happened.

The `self.exposureHintView` here is a custom subclass of `UIView`, does it matter?

Why?

Comment: I've found this to be flaky on the simulator - I'd advise testing on a real device.

Comment: I'm working with a real device... How to solve this?

Comment: Post your code for exposureHintView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[_AboutView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 510)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Use this code to change the position of your view

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know why transform does not do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you are create exposureHintView in storyboard or XIB file without code programmatically.

Try to do as the follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Init exposureHintView
    UIView* exposureHintView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame(sampleFrame)];
    [self addSubView: exposureHintView];

    //Set transform
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, -100);
    [self.exposureHintView setTransform:transform];

    //Commit animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0
                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
          NSLog(@"Begin!");
          CGAffineTransform newTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
          [self.exposureHintView setTransform:newTrans];
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"End %d", finished);
    }];
```

The reason here is your could not set Frame or Transform or some another attribute of this UIView in >>ViewDidLoad when you using storyboard or XIB